# Restoring file from recycle bin to a deleted original folder

Tags: windows, file-management, recycle-bin

Just say in the past I had a folder. Inside this folder I had a file. I deleted the file and it went to the recycle bin. Later on, I deleted the folder that the file was in and this also went to the recycle bin.

Some time passes, say six months, and I delete the folder mentioned above from the recycle bin and I "restore" the file.

Where does the file go?

Comment: Did you try to locate it using the built-in search function? You did check that the folder wasn't re-created right?

Comment: Well, is this what is meant to happen????? We tried searching for the file. It could be hidden? Maybe we didn't do a full search? Again, my specific question is, what happens when this operation is performed?

Comment: It is for me, after a short test. What kind of time passed between the deletion of the folder form the recycle bin and the restore or the file? Was the original location still accessible? Did you just try to navigate to it? Did you just hit restore or drag the file out of the recycle bin? How did you perform the search? In order to search the drive you would have to start the search e.g. from an explorer window showing the root (C:\, assuming you're using the built-in search feature).

Comment: 1. 6 months. 2. No. 3. No. 4. No. 5. Via the searchbox in the file explore. As you say, we may not have been at the root. I will get back to you. Thanks.

Comment: Found in the C:/ directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Where does the file go?

It is restored to it's original location (the directory is restored as well).

**Before Deletion:**

```
> dir test\*.txt
 Volume in drive F is Expansion
 Volume Serial Number is 3656-BB63

 Directory of F:\test\test

03/02/2017  13:43                 0 test.txt
               1 File(s)              0 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  1,704,590,606,336 bytes free
```

**After Deletion/Before Restore:**

```
> dir test\*.txt
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

[image]

**After Restore:**

```
> dir test\*.txt
 Volume in drive F is Expansion
 Volume Serial Number is 3656-BB63

 Directory of F:\test\test

03/02/2017  13:43                 0 test.txt
               1 File(s)              0 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  1,704,590,606,336 bytes free
```